# Result Window in ArcGIS 10.1 is not Opening

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geoprocessing

I booted up ArcMap 10.1 today and found out the [**Results Window**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Using_the_Results_window/002100000013000000/) was not opening up.

Background info:

- ArcMap is running through a virtualization program through at my company.
- Similar issue has came up in the past but with the search window not showing up.
- IT couldn't figure out what caused the issue with the search windows not opening up so they uninstalled the virulization program cleared the cache associated with ArcGIS.
- I noticed whenever I click on Geoprocessing->Results (I have also added in the results button through customization), the right edge in the following [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/n84s9fjdv4mydkr/ArcGIS%20Result%20Window%20Issue.jpg) blinks.
- I noticed a windows update went through last night so that may be the culprit?  Then again, how did the search windows get borked?

I've scoured  stack-exchange/internet and could not find any info relating to this issue. Tools successfully run and I can view the history log as mentioned [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002100000035000000) but i really need to view the results window so I can rerun various tools again without filling out the parameters again.

Does anybody know of any registry keys/services that I can look into that that may need to be tweaked?

I don't  want to resort to IT since I know for a fact they will uninstall everything, in turn loosing all my defaults e.g. shortcut keys, toolbars, and document customization.

Comment: is it possible it's opening off-screen. I have seen this happen when a dual monitor setup has one monitor taken away. Some video card drivers have an option for *prohibit windows from opening off screen*, that might be worth chasing up. If not you can try reset-to-default by finding and renaming your normal.gxt (it's in %appdata%\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcCatalog) or similar depending on your version.

Comment: That's a good thought. I just took a quick look but didn't find anything. I'll do some more digging around in the windows 7/Nvdia settings and see what I can find.  What's odd is that yesterday the results windows was showing up docked right underneath the ArcToolbox (Pretty sure its docked there by default when both are open.) and that's how have my normal.mxd set up.

Comment: I think nVidia active desktop provides that option, first you need to activate the *active desktop* and then you can get to the checkbox about preventing windows opening off-screen. Try that first because if you delete/rename your normal it will also destroy all your customizations.

Comment: Found the option:  Its in nView Desktop Manager->Windows Manager->Window Control->Prevent windows from opening off-screen. Didn't work but that's good to know! I tried Alt+M+Space bar then selected move from the menu to see if i could move any windows open in ArcMap but had had no luck. Tried Ctrl+Shift+Tab to cycle through ArcMap windows but that only works for Attribute Table.

Comment: I renamed the normal.gxt and it did have some effect: I wasn't able to open up ArcToolbox :-) I ended up backing up my normal.mxd and deleting that along with the normal.gxt and it looks like it solved the issue.  I brought in my backed up normal.mxd and I got all my customization's back.  I'm calling it a night for now.  When I come in tomorrow, I'll see if the problem arises again.  If not I will close off my question.

Comment: That's good news. Perhaps put that in as an answer for your own question just in case other users have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the [Results Window](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002100000013000000) to show up again by deleting the following files:

- normal.gxt *(%AppData%\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcCatalog)*
- normal.mxt *(%AppData%\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcMap\Templates)*
- normal.mxd *(%AppData%\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcMap\Templates)*

Booting up ArcMap recreates the new files setting .  I'm under the impression that one of these files was corrupt which kept the results window from opening up.

**Note**: If you want to keep your customization's, it's recommended to back up your normal. mxt and normal.mxd before deleting so they can be replaced later on.  I would also suggest deleting normal.gxt first and then booting up ArcMap to see if problems are resolved.  If problems still persist, delete the other two files.

**Sources:** [1](http://blog.geocortex.com/2009/06/16/suddenly-arccatalog-won-t-open/),[2](http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/18729),[3](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/78692),[4](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/About_configuring_the_user_interface/00v000000014000000/)