# ArcMap Dockable Search Window not launching

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, search-window

I'm running ArcGIS 10.5 on Windows 10, which I just updated from build 1511 to 1709. It has caused several problems; I don't know if this is related, but the timing seemed to coincide with my ArcGIS problem so I thought I'd include as much detail as possible.

The dockable Search window has disappeared from ArcMap. It still launches from ArcCatalog. I have followed the suggestions in:

- [ArcMap 10.5.1 search window not showing properly](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260353);
- [Search window not opening in ArcMap?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/237724); and
- [Result Window in ArcGIS 10.1 is not Opening](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108223)

most of which recommend deleting the map templates like `normal.mxt`(which I've tried), or trying to find a hidden, off-screen pane.

I also found [Moving an un-docked ArcToolbox from secondary screen to the main monitor](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/158650) which suggests editing the registry to reset entries for the pane states, but it only works if there is an entry at all for the window in question, which I don't have; it also means that it isn't just hiding off the edge of a display (usually in my experience, moving to-and-from dual displays will leave a small edge of the offending pane on the edge of the remaining screen, anyways).

I opened up the registry and built a little table of CLSIDs from ArcCatalog, since the Search window in it is working just fine. I used that (ProgID `esriCatalogUI.SearchDockableWindow`) to find the entry in the ArcObjects SDK [ArcCatalog documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000020000000), so that I could compare it with the [ArcMap documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/ArcMap_commands/00010000029s000000/), and hopefully locate the right entry and find a way to insert it into the existing registry keys.

But I'm a little hesitant to mess with registry keys *at all*, let alone trying to insert or alter an existing key. `DockingPaneLayouts.panestate` has several keys *after* the panes themselves: If only Pane-1 through Pane-3 are the only actual pane objects (Table of Contents, Toolbox, Identify, etc.), then how would I know what to edit in Pane-4 through Pane-12 and the Summary key?

Would it be worth it to download the ArcObjects SDK and try to instantiate a Search window from a script?

Or would it be safe to delete the entire `DockingPaneWindows` entry in hopes that ArcMap would generate new valid entries?

We have maintenance on our licenses, but I'd like to give GIS SE a shot before opening a ticket. I realize none of this is quicker or easier than reinstalling ArcGIS, but I'd rather find a real solution to the problem, hopefully one that can contribute to the knowledge base here.

Comment: Have you had multiple monitors on your PC in the past?  Your search pane may be on another monitor.  You may need to attach another monitor to see it (and move it over)

Comment: Please be aware that GIS does not aim to be a replacement for Esri support so, if you are paying for maintenance, then I think you should be using it for this one.  Personally I would have uninstalled and re-installed for those symptoms as almost my first test.

Comment: @PolyGeo thanks, I thought it would be nice to have something in the SE knowledge base for future users, as these questions seem to come up and never properly get addressed. I'll contact Esri support, and if I can get a more satisfactory answer than, "reinstall the software," then I'll self-answer so the community benefits.